# Enable PHP support for postgresql in Ubuntu 11.04 server

Tags: php, postgresql, apache2, ubuntu-11.04

I've installed `Apache2` with `PHP5` support and everything works there.  I've installed `PostgreSQL` and am able to connect to it using the terminal and execute SQL statements.

PROBLEM: I can't get a working connection between my `PHP` scripts and the `PostgreSQL` database.  I have installed the `php5-pgsql` packaged from the repositories, but the connection just won't work.

I get the following error message:

> PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in
> /var/www/[myfile].php on line [X]

How do I enable support for `PostgreSQL` connections in `PHP5` in ubuntu 11.04?

EDIT: Checked `phpinfo()` and found no entries for `PostgreSQL`.  I don't know why that is so, I DID install `php5-pgsql` package for ubuntu 11.04.

Here is what worked:  I installed `phppgadmin` from the Ubuntu repositories.  Not only does this make a nice tool available for me now, it also installed the needed packages for `PHP` to connect to `postgresql`.

After that, it was all in the connection parameters.  It wouldn't connect to the database on the local server until I defined the connection `host`, `port`, `database`, `user`, and `password` in that order in `pg_connect()`.

I still don't know why installing `php5-pgsql` on my own didn't enable `PostgreSQL` connections from `PHP`.  Any input on this would be helpful.

Comment: echo phpinfo(); and see if the PostgreSQL database is enabled

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Install the php5-pgsql package solves the problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=783869#post783869). (depending on the version ... php4-pgsql for php4)

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Remember to restart Apache.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

--Note that it might be hard if you do not administer your server.

Comment: in Fedora, you can enter `dnf install php-pgsql`

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 14.04, apache2, php5, postgres 9.11.3.  Seems weird but I had done:  "service apache2 restart" before and skipped the "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart" method.  Just now I did the "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart" method instead of using "service" and suddenly I no longer get the PHP/postgress configuration database connection errors any more.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Currently, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Me too was facing same problem while Fetching the Postgress Database values using Php so i resolved it by using the below commands.

Mine PHP version is 7.0, so i tried the below command.

`apt-get install php-pgsql` 
**Remember to restart Apache**.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

***Below is my code , might be someone get benefited :***

### - *testdb.php*

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
            <tr> 
                <td> 
                    Friend ID 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                     Name 
                </td> 

            </tr> 
        <?php 
        $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=root port=5432'); 

        $query = "SELECT * FROM account"; //account is name of table 

        $result = pg_query($query); 
        if (!$result) { 
            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
            echo pg_last_error(); 
            exit(); 
        } 

        while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $myrow['id'], htmlspecialchars($myrow['name']));
        } 
        ?> 
        </table> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only conclusion I can come up with is that phppgadmin installed all of the needed packages to make PHP5 connect to PostgreSQL.  I have looked at the dependencies, and I believe that I either didn't install them at all or didn't install them correctly.

I require no more help in this arena, as I have a working setup and know at least one method of getting to that point.